# Show that $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_iY_i-\overline{X}\overline{Y})$ is an unbiased estimator of $\text{Cov}[X,Y].$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Assume that $(X_1,Y_1),...,(X_n,Y_n)$ is a sample on a two-dimensional
>   random variable $(X,Y)$ and that $E[X^2], \ E[Y^2]$ and $E[XY]$ are
>   all finite so that the variances and covariance are well-defined. Show
>   that
>
> $$S=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_iY_i-\overline{X}\overline{Y})$$ is an
>   unbiased estimator of $\text{Cov}[X,Y].$

So I'm supposed to show that $E[S]=\text{Cov[X,Y]}.$ Now

$$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_iY_i-\overline{X}\overline{Y})\right]=\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_iY_i]-nE[\overline{X}\overline{Y}]=n(E[XY]-E[\overline{X}\overline{Y}]).\tag1$$

According to the formula for variance the last step in $(1)$ can be rewritten as

$$n(\mu_x\mu_y+\text{Cov}[X,Y]-(\mu_x\mu_y+\text{Cov}[\overline{X}\overline{Y}]))=\text{Cov}[X,Y]-\text{Cov}[\overline{X}\overline{Y}])), \tag2$$

where $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ are the respective mean.

**Questions:**

1. In $(2)$, I understand that from the covariance formula we get 
   $$\mu_x\mu_y=E[X]E[Y]=E[XY]-\text{Cov}[X,Y],$$
   but why is it also equal to
   $$\mu_x\mu_y=E[X]E[Y]=E[XY]-\text{Cov}[\overline{X}\overline{Y}]?$$
   Shouldn't the sample means with overline cause any difference?
2. How do I proceeed from here?

Comment: The overline quantities are defined as summations divided by n. Write them out, and expand the product of the averages over X and Y as a double summation and spit that double summation into a diagonal part where the indices are the same and a non-diagonal part where you sum over values for the indices that are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, see that $E(\overline X)=\mu_x$ and $E(\overline Y)=\mu_y$ because:
$$
E(\overline X)=E(\frac 1n\sum_i X_i)=\frac 1n\sum E(X_i)=\frac 1n (n\mu_x)=\mu_x.
$$
For the second question, the solutions follows as:
$$
\text{Cov}[\overline X\overline Y]=E[(\overline X-\mu_x)(\overline Y-\mu y)]=E(\overline X\overline Y)-\mu_x\mu_y.
$$
Now see that
$$
E(\overline X\overline Y)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j}E(X_iY_j)=\frac 1n E(XY)+\frac{n-1}{n}\mu_x\mu_y.
$$
Hence:
$$
\text{Cov}[\overline X\overline Y]=\frac 1n E(XY)-\frac 1n  \mu_x\mu_y=\frac 1n \text{Cov}(XY).
$$
Plug this in  and you have:
$$
E(S)=\frac{1}{n-1}\times n\times (\text{Cov}(XY)-\frac 1n \text{Cov}(XY))=\text{Cov}(XY).
$$

Comment: Where does this follow from $$E[\overline X\overline Y)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j}E(X_iY_j] ?$$ Is it generally true that $$E[\overline{X_1}...\overline{X_k}] = \frac{1}{n^k}\sum_{i,j}E[X_iX_j]$$

Comment: Just multiply $\overline X=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $\overline Y=\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j$.

Comment: Ahh... okay I see then it is generally true i believe. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please elaborate the last equality here: $$
E(\overline X\overline Y)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j}E(X_iY_j)=\frac 1n E(XY)+\frac{n-1}{n}\mu_x\mu_y.
$$

Comment: If $i=j$, then $E(X_iY_j)=E(X_iY_i)=E(XY)$ and there are $n$ different pairs as such; if $i\neq j$ then $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent therefore $E(X_iY_j)=\mu_x\mu_y$ and there are $\binom{n}{2}$ of such pairs.

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to compute this without using combinatorial reasonings?

Comment: I do not think so; at some moment you have to count the terms that are independent and those that are not.

Comment: When I compute $\frac{1}{n^2}{n\choose 2}$ i get $\frac{n-1}{2n}$ and not $\frac{n-1}{n}.$ I just use the factorial and binomial formula to expand.

Comment: @Parseval oh sorry; you should count ordered pairs so the binomail is incorrect and you get $n(n-1)$ terms.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how you got $n(n-1)$.

Comment: You want to count the number of pairs $X_iY_j$ with $i\neq j$; there are $n$ different ways to choose $i$. For each fixed $i$, there are $n-1$ choice for $j$ (all numbers excluding $i$). Therefore we have $n(n-1)$  different terms.